# Scala sbt run - "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Tags: scala, sbt

Things run without any problem when I work on IntelliJ, but when I try to compile and run my Scala code in the command line (with `sbt run`) the following error message pops up.

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: akka/event/LogSource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: akka/event/LogSource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

And my Scala version is 2.9.2.

```
$ scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

I barely started learning Scala a few weeks ago, so if anyone could provide some advice on what I should look into, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turned out that there was a mismatch in the JRE version. In the IntelliJ project settings the project SDK was set to be Java 1.8 (on my local machine), whereas JRE 1.7 was installed on the Ubuntu system (an EC2 instance).

In Ubuntu 14.04, the OpenJDK 1.8 is not available by default so the following repository must be added manually. Then the OpenJDK can be installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

The default Java version in the system can be changed by running the following command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Once I installed `openjdk-8-jre` and adjusted the default Java version in the system, the `sbt run` command ran without any issue.

Comment: I had similar issue on Eclipse Neon.3 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doing updating default jre via `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: I had a miss match java version with windows...which this answer pointed to

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. You should accept it. It's fine to answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Mac and trying to learn Scala by following a simple Scala tutorial. I got this error when I am trying to run the app.

**Reason**:
My installed java version was 8. But on my Terminal the version I was using was 7.

**Fix**:
I updated the java version to the newest version and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Update to correct java version and compile again. It should work fine

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same proble with CentOS-7.6, here is my solution:

1. run `vim /etc/profile` in command line, check your Environment variable to find the jdk version, change it to jdk-1.8. Save and quit safely.
   [example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGpur.png)
2. run `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java`, choose version-1.8.
3. run `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config javac`, also choose version-1.8.
4. run `source /etc/profile` to make the settings work.

By doing the four steps, I was able to run command sbt again without orror.[sbt picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34c59.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly started getting this error on Windows 10. Turned out my path had somehow reverted to point to an old version of the java jdk. To be thorough, I first upgraded to the latest jdk (from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) for Oracle), which for me was 8u152. I then corrected my path entry to

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin
```

(This would be a little different for the 32 bit version.) I then verified that `javac -version` indeed returned 1.8.0_152 (make sure to open a fresh terminal - an already open one will remember the old path).

And then `sbt run` worked. (Again remembering to do this from a fresh terminal so path is fresh.)